# Laravel 4.2, Hash:make() does not work with Auth::user()->attempt()

Tags: php, laravel, hash, authentication

I am just trying for almost 24 hours to Laravel Auth to work. I am trying a very simple as follows:

Create a user:

```
$emailActivationCode = str_random(60);
$created = User::create([
   'email' => 'raju@mydomain.com',
   'password' => \Hash::make('raju@myhome'),
   'activation_code' => $emailActivationCode,
   'protected' => 1,
   'activated' => 1
]);
```

And I am trying right below of the code to login:

```
$user = \Auth::user()->attempt(array(
    'email'     => 'raju@mydomain.com',
    'password'  => 'raju@myhome',
    'activated' => 1
));
```

And my User model is as follows:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;
use Jacopo\Authentication\Models\User as JacopoUser;
use Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserExistsException;
use Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\LoginRequiredException;

class User extends JacopoUser implements UserInterface
{
    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    public static function boot()
    {
        static::setHasher(new \Cartalyst\Sentry\Hashing\NativeHasher);
    }

    public function fundings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Funding', 'users_id');
    }

    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Project', 'users_id');
    }
}
```

But the login always fails. I could not see any error message either nor I can login. I tried to google but most of the solutions have suggested exactly what I have implemented.

Can any Laravel gurus out there suggest a better solution or work around of this issue ? And it would be really nice of you if you reply as soon as possible.

**Edit:**
It seems the hash generated by Hash:make() is invalid/wrong. I copied a hash previously generated in another project and it works the above code quite good. How come that hash is generated wrong ? Does anyone know the cases ?

Comment: Is the authentication library you're using comptable with the underlying Auth facade? Auth::attempt, to my knowledge, only works with Laravel's built in authentication contracts.

Comment: I am not really sure since that was done by another developer. Can you please suggest a better library/package for Laravel 4.2 that does the multiple ACL ?

Comment: Yes but it seems the version that we are using seems compatible with Laravel 4.2 as mentioned here https://github.com/intrip/laravel-authentication-acl/blob/1.2/docs/index.md.

Comment: Make sure your user table's password field is long enough to fit the full hash ("CHAR(60)" is recommended).

Answer (score 0):

Right here is a potential issue

```
Auth::user()->attempt
```

attempt is a function on Auth, you don't return the user model then attempt.

```
if (Auth::attempt(array(...))
$user = Auth::user();
```

Comment: Well in that case, it successes even I pass wrong credentials. In fact, this code was written by another developer and he was saying it is with user because we have multi level users in the system (multiple roles). I am not that good in Laravel but I can go ahead if I get some direction.

Comment: But without a logged in user Auth::user() should return nothing of value